# Unable to use "pod install" in MacOS 11.0

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoapods

I updated my Mac OS and try to use "pod install" for my .xcworkspace. However I get below error:

"Ignoring ffi-1.12.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.12.2"

Could you please recommend how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Are you using the system ruby? If so, step one is to stop doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

Make sure you have the latest `pod` installed, `pod --version` should be `1.10.0` (or later).

Do `pod install --repo-update`.

Comment: thank you, I did a lot of things and the last one worked: sudo gem install cocoapods